# How can I fetch data asynchronously in backbone using backbone layout manager?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-layout-manager

I'm having a problem in Layout Manager to get the view to wait to render until a bunch of AJAX calls have completed and successfully populated a collection which I pass to subviews.

Here's my initialization function:

```
initialize : function(){
            var collection;

            collection = new BobLawBlaw.Collection();
            collection.fetch();

            this.collection = collection;
        }
```

My fetch is a little complicated :

```
fetch : function(){
            var that = this;

            return $.when.apply(null, TL.reporting.getData.call(this, 125)).done(function(xhr1, xhr2){
                var data1 = xhr1[0].data, data2 = xhr2[0].data, dates = data1.date,

                // do a bunch of stuff with the data i get above to construct the models how i need
                models = [
                   // bunch of objects using the data
                ];

                that.add(models);
            });
        }
```

That `getData` function gathers the deferreds from TWO ajax calls and returns them in an array, thus allowing that `done` function to get triggered when both calls are done. This works as expected and I can get all the data I need.

However, the flow in the initialize function does not stop when that fetch is triggered, so the collection is not populated in time before LayoutManager goes on to beforeRender. How can I fetch asyncronously, but make the initialize function wait until both ajax calls complete AND populate the collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it the Backbone way, yous should trigger a 'reset' event in your `done` callback. You then listen to this event in your view to launch the `render` function. Replacing the `that.add( models )` with `that.reset( models )` will add the models AND trigger the event for you.

Then in the view's initialize function:

```
// ...
this.listenTo( collection, 'reset', this.render, this );
```

And the `this.render` function will be called when the fetch is done.

Answer (score 2):

You can always `listenTo` to events on the collection.

```
initialize : function() {

   this.collection = new BobLawBlaw.Collection();
   this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
   this.collection.fetch();
}
```

So if you listenTo the `sync` event , the `render` method will be called when the collection is in sync with the server.